# Wso2 esb 5 tooling port offset not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I am using new Mars 2 with esb tooling. I have added an local esb server with a carbon offset of 5. When I start run the server it starts correctly but the offset 5 does not have any impact none of the ports are incremented. 
Starting the esb server from cmd works fine with offset.

Anyone else faced the same issue?

Here is the screen shot of the step while adding new server to eclipse, and I am giving the offset as **5**. But when i start the server it starts on the 9443.

[image]

Comment: in which file you updated the Offeset value?

Comment: @AnushkaEkanayake i have edited my question with the image of new server wizard of eclipse where i am setting the "Carbon Server Offset" to 5.

Comment: check in the following file, whether the changed is applied properly. Else, change the offset value manually,<ESB HOME> \repository\conf\Carbon.xml . Search for offset tag

Comment: Yes the eclipse is not updating the carbon.xml file with the changed offset. Updating it manually and then starting the server from eclipse will run the server with incremented ports but in eclipse server status will remain as starting and then eventually it will time out with an error and the server will be stopped.

Answer (score 1):

The screen you have attached, actually reads values from configuration files inside ESB and populates accordingly. So if you want an offset to your ports, then you should first change the following in `<ESB_HOME>`/repository/conf/carbon.xml

```
<Offset>4</Offset>
```

There after if you load the server configuration, you will see the Carbon server offset correctly reflecting as you have specified as below. The developer studio does not write values to files rather reads values from the them. So if a change is required to the default values, they should be first changed in the respective file.

[New server dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfNTr.png)

Comment: Thanks for your the info. Yes updating the offset in the carbon.xml file does show up in the New server dialog box. But the problem is that when you start the server from eclipse the status remains as starting and never turns to started.

Comment: I guess this is because eclipse esb server plugin may not be considering the changed service port which should be 9767 when offset is set to 4. In previous developer studio 3.8.0 with eclipse luna updating the offset from the new server dialog box was updating the carbon.xml and things worked just fine, but looks like this is broken in the new tooling.